# Windows Explorer: What video file did I view last?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have a lot of episodes on my computer, but I always forget, what episode I watched last.

Is there a plugin or some possibility to see in Windows Explorer, what file I opened the last time or when I opened my files? (So I know, what episode I have to watch next)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your video player should have a recent videos list, often under the `File` menu. If you need further information on this, you need to specify which video player you're using.

Comment: Additionally, iTunes lets you [create smart playlists](http://www.macworld.com/article/1136824/audiobooks.html). You could create one for all the episodes of a particular show that has 0 plays. This way, once the episode has been watched, it gets deleted from that playlist. You can also save your position in each episode in case you stop watching in the middle of it.

Comment: I use VLC Player.

Comment: Only thing that works for me, Create a subfolder and move the watched ones into it. Moves to the same partition are fast, because only the pointer to the location changes, so it is fast easy , syncs with a backup, and independant of anything that changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is usually implemented by the video player. You said you use VLC, so see the menu `Media` > `Open Recent Media`.

[[image: Screenshot of VLC recent media menu]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXI6w.png)

---

If you pin the media player to the taskbar, you can click (hold) on the program icon and drag up, there should be a `Recent` list.

[[image: Screenshot of VLC taskbar pin]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52mq6.png)

Windows Media Player actually implements even more functionality through this, that `Tasks` list... though I'm not sure whether `Frequent` means `Recent`, so this may not work with WMP.

[[image: Screenshot of WMP taskbar pin]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr4OA.png)

---

You can also pin the media player to the start menu. Just mouseover/click the arrow to the right of the name.

[[image: Screenshot of VLC start menu pin]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YH3b.png)

Comment: +1 for screen shots buddy. just i was typing the same but you beat me in typing............

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is right click in the folder where you saved your video's, from pop-up menu select view then details, the details view shows you all the date, time when last the filed was opened

Comment: I don't think Windows shows you this by default. You need to show the `Date Accessed` column to see when each file was last accessed.